# Freeing memory in a function vs in the same scope

Tags: c, memory

Suppose I have the following linked list:

```
struct ListNode {
   int value;
   struct ListNode *next;
}
```

And I want to free the memory of my linked list `list` using the function `delete_list`:

```
void delete_list(struct ListNode *list) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        struct ListNode *temp = list;
        list = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct ListNode *list = create_digit_list(56458);
    list_print(list);
//    while (list != NULL) {
//        struct ListNode *temp = list;
//        list = temp->next;
//        free(temp);
//    }
    delete_list(list);
    list_print(list);
    return 0;
}
```

When I free my list in the same scope I get that `list` is `NULL`.
But for some reason when using the free my linked list using the my function `delete_list` and passing my `list` as a parameter, `list` isn't `NULL` and as a result the code prints an infinite loop of garbage.
What's the difference between the two ways? what's the correct way to extract the free operation to function?

Comment: `delete_list(list)` doesn't change the value of the variable `list`. Why do you think it would? When `delete_list(list)` returns, the node that `list` points to has been freed, so it is an error to try to use the value of `list`. C does not protect you from errors like this. That's your responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are two variables named `list`. One inside main function and another is the argument of the `delete_list` function. For simplicity let them be `list1` and `list2`.

When `list1` variable is freed inside the `main` function. The final value of the `list1` variable is `NULL`.

When you pass `list1` variable to the function `delete_list` its value gets copied to the `list2` variable present in the scope of `delete_list` function. When the function returns; the final value of `list2` variable is `NULL`. But `list1` still has original address of the struct which you already freed. This leads to garbage values being displayed.

Try renaming your variables and it would me much clearer. If you want you can pass your pointer as a reference which would also affect the original pointer and set it to `NULL`.

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by passing my pointer as a reference?

Comment: @KaliTheGreat In that case double pointers can be used 
`void delete_list( struct ListNode** p_list){ ... }`

for calling use `delete_list( &list )`

Also `p_list` inside the `delete_list` function should be dereferenced as `*p_list` everywhere list is used.